# Suspend mode does not work properly

Tags: suspend

elementary OS 5.0 Juno. Three Options How Suspend Mode Works. 1) Suspend working correctly - The screen is black, disks sleep, the power supply sleeps, the button of a power supply of the system unit blinks, 2) The screen is black, the power supply works, the button of a power supply of the system unit blinks, 3) The screen is black, but the computer does not go to sleep

Comment: Please specify your question. Do these 3 options (random behavior of suspend mode) describe the issue that you're experiencing?

Comment: Добрый день! Переход в ждущий режим на стационарном компьютере что в автомате (в настройках питания системы) что в ручном принудительном режиме происходит рандомно. То все правильно, но это редко, то в двух вариантах неправильно. Еще раз как неправильно. 1) Гаснет экран, кнопка питания системного блока моргает, вентиляторы охлаждения работают, работают ли HDD в это время я не знаю. Нажав на кнопку питания компьютер выходит из ждущего режима 2) Всё тоже самое, но кнопка питания горит постоянно и вывести комп из ждущего режима невозможно. Только перезагружать. Не знаю как прислать сюда логи...

Comment: Thanks for elaborate explanation! (But let's stick to English, so other users could participate too.)  Do you dual-boot elementary OS with Windows or some other OS (Ubuntu, Mint, etc)? If so, does your power button also behaves inconsistently in other OS?

Comment: The transition to suspend on a comp is random in the machine (in the system power settings) and in manual forced mode. That’s all right, but it’s rare, and in two cases it’s wrong. Once again, how wrong. 1) The screen goes blank, the power button of the system unit blinks, the cooling fans are working, whether the HDD is working at this time, I do not know. By pressing the power button, the computer exits standby mode 2) Everything is the same, but the power button is constantly on and it is impossible to bring the computer out of standby mode. Only reboot. I don’t know how to send logs here

Comment: Only elementary OS is installed on the computer, but the partition is encrypted

Comment: Successful sleep. Power Off
Sep 19 15:09:05 PC systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 19 15:09:05 PC systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Sep 19 15:09:05 PC kernel: [ 1823.869236] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep 19 15:09:05 PC systemd-sleep[19817]: Suspending system...
Sep 19 15:09:06 PC kernel: [ 1823.869240] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.

Answer (score 0):

If elementary OS is the only OS installed on your PC, it's hard to tell, whether it's elementary OS' fault or Ubuntu's - as elementary OS Juno is Ubuntu-18.04-based.

I'm dual-booting elementary OS with Windows, and my PC suspends normally in both. My PC's power LED is off during sleep/suspend, but as far as I know, on other PCs it may as well blink, because this behavior is motherboard-specific.

Anyway, as this random dysfunction might be hardware-specific (old PC, failing HDD) or software-specific (some process or app messing with power settings and preventing normal suspend), you can upload your logs to a hosting and update your question with a download link, so more technically proficient users than myself could have a look at them.

Comment: Link to the log file.   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hz-SPCjpcall6akN0DAUIasX62TU9nAS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: PC:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version: core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:printing-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: elementary
Description: elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Release: 5.0
Codename: juno

Comment: An interesting feature. If you put the computer into suspend mode for some period of time, then the first time everything is fine. For the second time the screen goes blank , but the fans work, and the power button blinks. And the third time the computer does not go into suspend mode, the screen goes blank and then you can work only after a reboot.

Comment: Interesting indeed, although I wouldn't call it a feature, but rather a bug :) Looks like it accumulates gradually, in discreet steps. Based on your description, I'm guessing that the actual root of the problem may be incorrect waking from suspend mode, not going into it (which is rather a consequence). I wonder, what  would more experienced elementary OS users suggest to solve this issue.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1774950

Comment: This bug is relevant to older kernel version (4.14.47) only, and, according to launchpad, should've been fixed for newer kernel versions (currently, 4.15.0-64). What's your kernel version? (type `uname -r`)

Comment: It seems the issue has been resolved. I'm testing. There was a little swap. With 8 GB of RAM, swap was 1 GB. I installed swapspace and made an additional 4 gb swap file.

Comment: Congrats! ) If you satisfied with your solution, I suggest updating your own question with it, so other users may benefit from it.

Comment: And still the reason is in the core. With an enlarged swap file and on the kernel 4.15.0.65.74, the same error. On the kernel 4.19.75 and 4.20.17 everything works fine.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, it's definitely a kernel-hardware issue. Older kernels seem to be less compatible with (or totally unaware of) your specific hardware.

Comment: My opinion is that the kernel release is to blame. In the kernel version prior to 4.15.0.64 suspend worked fine.